# Finding the shortest path between nodes in graph

Tags: c, transition, state-machine

I have a state machine that looks like this:

```
           G--H
          /
A--B--C--D--E--F
```

I want to have a function, goToState(target) that has as an input argument the target state, and then the function will execute all the transitions starting from the current state until it reaches the target state.

For example, let's say that the current state is B and we call goToState(F). Then the function will do the following state transitions B->C, C->D, D->E, E->F.

The transitions work both ways so if current state is F and we call goToState(G), then the function will do F->E, E->D, D->G.

If we had a linear state machine (eg, no branch G--H), then I would just do an array of functions for each transition, in the legal order, and then find the index for current state and the index for the target state and call all the transition function in between those two indexes in a for loop.

However now that I have a branch, this method would not work. What would be the most efficient way to encode the legal transitions and to implement a function that executes them in the right order based on the target state in C?

EDIT:
As some other users very well pointed out, what I'm looking for is some sort of path finding algorithm that finds the shortest path between two states. I just couldn't find the right words to formulate it properly in the original post. I need the simplest path finding algorithm that would work for a state diagram as shown above. The state diagram will never get more complex than this so the algorithm doesn't need to cover any other scenarios either.

EDIT2:
Updated the title to better describe the problem.
Your comments helped me find the right terminology so I can search the web for the solution.

Comment: Are you asking about how to program state transitions to a specific, directly reachable state or about a path finding algorithm to find out which next state to select? Seems like you are not focussing on one problem here. Please focus on one problem, either by demonstrating that you can do the transition to a reachable state or by asking specifically about how to do that.

Comment: A *graph*? Possibly a *tree* if there can't be any cycles?

Comment: @Some programmer dude, How would those help find the right branch?!

Comment: This is better described with graph theory: You are seeking a path between two nodes in an undirected graph. Each state in your machine is a node in a [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)), each transition is an edge between two nodes, and transitions can go either way (edges are undirected). If all you have to work with is the state diagram, you want to [find a path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathfinding) between two nodes.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, Re "*If all you have to work with is the state diagram*", The question is specifically about how it could be augmented.

Comment: @ikegami: Not clear to me from the phrasing in the problem statement.

Comment: Your example is a very specific case. In general, a state machine can be any directed graph (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)#Directed_graph) with more than one way to transition from any state X to any state Y. It could also be described by a two-dimensional state table. You might have to find the shortest path from state X to state Y. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem)

Comment: If your goal is for the code executing the transitions between the start state and goal state to be simple/efficient, then you can precompute a table (or other data structure) in which looking up the start state and the goal state gives a precomputed list of states in between (or equivalent information, such as the “direction” to go in at each decision point). Then there may be a question of how to compute such a table. You should update the question to clarify.

Comment: Ugh, I would vote to close this as needs details, but there are two bad votes already—one that it needs debugging details, which it does not since it is a question about algorithms, not about bugs in code, and one that it is seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more, which it is not except under an inappropriate inclusion of algorithms in “more.” Voting to close would result in Stack Overflow listing one of the earlier confusing reasons.

Comment: If all you have is the beginning (current) and destination state, you could use any common path-finding algorithm to find the "path" (list of states) to follow and pass through. If there's some kind of ordering between states then you could solve it even easier with a tree-traversal.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil Re "*Not clear to me from the phrasing in the problem statement.*", Yes, there would have been no point to my comment if it was clear to you. That's why I clarified it for you. They specifically mentioned their asking for an efficient storage format, now how to make do with a generic graph.

Comment: @ikegami: You did not clarify anything; you merely asserted your unexplained opinion about what the question asks. The post asks for “the most efficient way to encode the legal transitions.” But encoding the transitions efficiently is different from providing data that efficiently guides a path from a given start to a given end. The wording is unclear.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, Re "*you merely asserted your unexplained opinion about what the question asks.*", Yes. You're the one that finds it unclear, not me. No idea why you think asking how to encode the data means "oh you must have a simple graph, so you must be asking how to find a path in a graph". But that's not what the question says.

Comment: @ikegami: I do not think and have not written that asking how to encode the data means OP must have a simple graph and must be asking how to find a path in the graph.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, Whatever you want to call it. "If all you have to work with is the state diagram" clearly missed the point of the question

Comment: @ikegami: The meaning of that sentence is that if all one has is the state diagram (and one wants to find a path between two nodes), then they need a path-finding algorithm. It does not state that the fact they have a simple graph means they are asking how to find a path. The fact they are asking how to find a path is derived from the statement in the question that they want the function to execute transitions from the current state to the target state. It is not derived from the fact that they have transition data.

Comment: @ikegami: It is evident from the post that OP wants some way of executing transitions from a start state to an end state. It is not clear whether they want a path-finding algorithm or want a way of encoding precomputed paths that are found with a path-finding algorithm. Those are two different things.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, Re "*The meaning of that sentence is that if all one has is the state diagram (and one wants to find a path between two nodes), then they need a path-finding algorithm.*", Oh, then you're just completely wrong, then

Comment: @ikegami: The entire purpose of that comment was to restate the question in graph terminology, not to present a solution to the problem. It is in fact true that if  one only has the state diagram and wants to find a path between two nodes/states, they need a path-finding algorithm.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, but like I said above, you're presuming a graph. The question is what to use. Graph is an answer, or at least presumes an answer. It's not the premise.

Comment: @ikegami: No, I did not presume a graph. The post describes a problem with data that is equivalent to a graph, so I explained how the problem is described with graph theory.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, Then explain why you incorrectly concluded a path-finding algorithm is needed?

Comment: @ikegami: I correctly concluded that to find a path, a path-finding algorithm is needed. What makes you think OP does not want to find a path from a start state to a goal state?

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, There are O(1) path-finding algorithms? This can be done in O(1)

Comment: @ikegami: What is “this”? Is “this” finding the path given only the states and their transitions? Or is “this” finding the path given precomputed data from the states and their transitions?

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, Getting that path. Yes, it could be obtained using a path-finding algorithm. But as you now acknowledge, it could also be in some precomputed form.

Comment: @ikegami: Yes, it can be in some precomputed form. Of course, precomputing it still requires a path-finding algorithm, to do the precomputing. But this has nothing to do with the question of whether OP is asking for some way of encoding the transitions that serves path finding on the fly or is asking for some way of encoding precomputed paths. They have not stated their question clearly.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, Those aren't two possible questions, those are two possible answers to the question

Comment: @ikegami: No, OP could be asking for one or the other. The post is unclear.

Comment: @ Eric Postpischil, It is unclear, but because they ask for an efficient solution without defining any parameters for what that means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer on GeeksforGeeks website: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shortest-path-unweighted-graph/

It's a modified version of the Breadth-First Search algorithm and does exactly what I need!

Thank you all for your answers and comments. They helped me find the right terminology to search for the right solution online.

Answer (score 1):

You can model the states as an array of structs, each of which contains a function pointer for the transition and an array of possible destination states.

Then, create a function that takes the current and destination state and have it loop through the list of possible states.  If one matches the destination, put that at the start of an empty list of states and return the list.  If not, recurse through each possible intermediate state until either one returns a nonempty list and add the current state to the front of the list.

After the recursive function returns, you can iterate through the list running the transitions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef void (*func)(void);    // modify as needed
typedef enum { NONE=-1, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, MAX_STATES } states;

struct transitions {
    func transition;
    states slist[MAX_STATES];
};

struct tlist {
    struct transitions *trans;
    struct tlist *next;
};

void trans_a(void) { printf("transition A\n"); }
void trans_b(void) { printf("transition B\n"); }
void trans_c(void) { printf("transition C\n"); }
void trans_d(void) { printf("transition D\n"); }
void trans_e(void) { printf("transition E\n"); }
void trans_f(void) { printf("transition F\n"); }
void trans_g(void) { printf("transition G\n"); }
void trans_h(void) { printf("transition H\n"); }

struct transitions transitions[] = {
    { trans_a, { B, NONE } },
    { trans_b, { A, C, NONE } },
    { trans_c, { B, D, NONE } },
    { trans_d, { C, G, E, NONE } },
    { trans_e, { D, F, NONE } },
    { trans_f, { E, NONE } },
    { trans_g, { D, H, NONE } },
    { trans_h, { G, NONE } }
};

struct tlist *getStates(states prev, states start, states end)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; transitions[start].slist[i] != NONE; i++) {
        if (transitions[start].slist[i] == prev) continue;
        if (transitions[start].slist[i] == end) {
            struct tlist *entry = malloc(sizeof *entry);
            entry->trans = transitions + start;
            entry->next = NULL;
            return entry;
        }
        struct tlist *list = getStates(start, transitions[start].slist[i], end);
        if (list) {
            struct tlist *entry = malloc(sizeof *entry);
            entry->trans = transitions + start;
            entry->next = list;
            return entry;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

void runStates(states start, states end)
{
    printf("from %d to %d\n", start, end);
    struct tlist *list = getStates(NONE,start,end);
    while (list) {
        struct tlist *tmp = list;
        list->trans->transition();
        list = list->next;
        free(tmp);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    runStates(A,H);
    runStates(A,E);
    runStates(E,A);
    runStates(F,H);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
from 0 to 7
transition A
transition B
transition C
transition D
transition G

from 0 to 4
transition A
transition B
transition C
transition D

from 4 to 0
transition E
transition D
transition C
transition B

from 5 to 7
transition F
transition E
transition D
transition G
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answers already posted are adequate to answer the question, but I want to add that this is a classical problem that is studied in the abstract mathematical field of theoretical computations. The mathematical model of computation that describes what you're asking for is called a Finite State Machine. An FSM is an abstract machine that contains (without going to deep into math jargon or notation):

1. An *input language*, which in your case is whatever you pass to the function to find out which *state* your program should transition to ("target" in my example)
2. A set of *states*, which in your case is A, B, C, D, E, F , G, and H
3. An *initial state*, which is whichever of the *set of states* above that your program starts in
4. A *transition function* that tells each state where to go from any given *state* given any input in the *input language* (the function "transtition" in my example)
5. A set of *final states* which is either empty or a subset of your *set of states*

The crux of your question is about item 4, the *transition function*. A C implementation of a transition function for an FSM that may fit your needs may look something like this:

```
//Model states as integers from 0-7 plus an extra invalid state for error handling
enum state{A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, invalid};

enum state transition(enum state current, enum state target){
  
  if(target < A || target > H || current < A || current > H)
    return invalid;
  else if(target == current)
    return current;

  switch(current){
    case A:
        return B;
    case B: //B and C have combinable transition behavior
    case C:
      if(target > current)
        return current + 1;
      else
        return current - 1;
    case D:
      if(target < D)
        return C;
      else if(target > F)
        return G;
      else
        return E;
    case E:
      if(target < E)
        return D;
      else
        return F;
    case F:
      return E;
    case G:
      if(target < G)
        return D;
      else
        return H;
    case H:
      return G;
    //Edge-cases have been managed so no need for default case
  }
}
```

Then in you can implement `goToState()` like so:

```
int goToState(enum state current,enum state target){

  while(current != target && current != invalid){
    current = transtition(current, target);
    handle(current);  //Do whatever must be done for whatever state we are in along the way
  }
  if(current == invalid)
    return -1; //Error code
  else
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Like I wrote in some other comment, my original formulation was not very descriptive of the problem. I was looking for an algorithm that finds the shortest path between two states.

Answer (score -1):

No matter the state machine, you'll want to avoid "stateghetti", which is what happens when each and every state makes multiple, local decisions on what state to execute next.

Instead, have each state return a result code. You can still have an array of function pointers no matter. Then at the top level of the program, write something along the lines of this pseudo:

```
while(...)
{
  result = state_machine[current_state]();
  current_state = evaluate(current_state, result);
}
```

The function `evaluate()` is the *only* place in your code where state transitions are allowed. Optionally it can double as your top-level error handler.

Then simply code down all dependencies you need inside this function:

```
...
if(state==C && result==OK)
  return D;

if(state==D)
{
  if(result==OK)
    return E;
  else
    return G;
}
...
```

Comment: What does this do to further the goal of finding a path from one given state to another? State machines are commonly used to process input, where the input directs the transition. This question does not involve that; its goal is to traverse a path from one given state to another given state.

Comment: @EricPostpischil This can be trivially expanded by either passing along the previous result or memorize them inside evaluate().

Comment: @Lundin maybe I didn't describe the problem very well. It's not a typical state machine that each state does some processing and yields the next state depending on conditions. What' I'm trying to solve is finding an easy way of finding the shortest path between two states.